# FPS drop after moved from Textures to TextureAtlas in LibGDX

Tags: textures, libgdx, frame-rate, texture-atlas

I've started using LibGDX some time ago and I was making a test project to get used to this library. I've created some images and added them to the assets folder and loaded each image as a `Texture` using the `AssetManager`. Everything was working fine and I had 60 FPS.

I wanted to work in a more efficient way so I packed all my images into an atlas using the TexturePacker tool. I loaded the atlas using the `AssetManager` again and started using `TextureRegion`s instead of `Texture`s.

After this change I've started to notice sudden drops in FPS from 60 to 50 and even 30 once. I've tried to change the pixel format to RGBA4444, I've made sure that the min and mag filter were both seth to `Nearest`, but still I see those annoying frame drops.

I'm not doing anything heavy in the game itself, it's currently some actors in a stage. I got some MoveActions and Animation, but nothing special yet.

Does anyone have a clue what can cause the FPS drop?

Thanks

Comment: Are you combining the textures into the atlas or are you simply having one texture per one atlas?

Comment: Of course I've combined them all into one atlas. I'm loading the atlas with the AssetManager and then holding a reference to each region using `findRegion`.